# Yii2: run console command from controller in vendor directory

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am doing some refactoring of our large work app. This involves separating out some tools I've build, like a schema/seed migration tool for the command line, in to their own repositories to be used by multiple applications.

If it's in console/controllers, it gets picked up. If I move them to their own repository and require it via Composer, how do I get Yii to know when I say `php yii db/up`, i mean go to the `new\vendor\namespace\DbController@actionup` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an extension (and load it through composer of course), you can locate `Module.php` inside, which will hold path to console controllers (that you can call with your terminal).

I will write my example for `common\modules\commander` namespace, for vendor extension your namespace will differ, but it work for all of them the same way.
So I have the following file structure for my extension

```
<app>
  common
    modules
      commander
        controllers
          • TestController.php
        • Module.php
```

My Module class looks as follow:

```
namespace common\modules\commander;
use yii\base\Module as BaseModule;
class Module extends BaseModule
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'common\modules\commander\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

And `TestController.php` is inherited from `yii\console\Controller`:

```
namespace common\modules\commander\controllers;
use yii\console\Controller;
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo 123;
    }
}
```

And the main part to make everything work is to register out Module.php in `console/config/main.php` settings

```
'modules' => [
    'commander' => [
        'class' => \common\modules\commander\Module::className(),
    ],
    ...
],
```

Here it is, now you can use your command like:

```
yii commander/test/index
```

And it'll print you `123`, showing that everything works and Console Controllers are located in different folders!

Comment: Well yerke, that was about as good an explanation as anyone could give for anything. Nailed it, works right away. Thank you!

Comment: You are Welcome, diabetesjones =)